# java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: TLSv1.2 SSLContext not available

Tags: ssl, tls1.2, java-17, tls1.3, java-security

`Getting this error on using BCFIPS jar 1.0.2.4 on jdk 17 with java.security file with following
values

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, RC4, DES, MD5withRSA, \
    DH keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL
# List of providers and their preference orders (see above):
#
security.provider.1=SUN
security.provider.2=SunRsaSign
security.provider.3=SunEC
security.provider.4=SunJSSE
security.provider.5=SunJCE
security.provider.6=SunJGSS
security.provider.7=SunSASL
security.provider.8=XMLDSig
security.provider.9=SunPCSC
security.provider.10=JdkLDAP
security.provider.11=JdkSASL
security.provider.12=SunPKCS11
```

The code was working fine with JDK 11 but starts failing on jdk 17.

Tried changing the used protocol version to TLSv1.3 but failed. Checked if jdk 17 is installed succesfully on my machine and checked the supported protocols, which are in jdk 17 and gave below output
[TLSv1.3, TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1, SSLv3, SSLv2Hello]`